# How can I intercept an incoming route in Angular?

Tags: angular, identityserver4, angular-routing

Some of my angular routes have path parameters. Angular separates these parameters using semicolons. When I navigate to IdentityServer for login, these semicolons are replaced with "%3B". This makes it so that Angular does not understand the returnUrl.

For example, when I navigate from http://localhost:5003/properties/property-details;accountNo=656401 to the login page and am redirected back...

I get this error:

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'properties/property-details%3BaccountNo%3D656401'`

**How can I configure Angular to interpret these "%3B" as ";"?**

Comment: Can you share your routes?

Comment: [{path: "property-details", component: PropertyDetailsComponent}]

Answer (score 0):

The solution I went with was to store the router.url in sessionStorage and then redirect to that url when redirected from the identity server.